# bash: make an array for the files in the same directory

Tags: arrays, bash

I am working with the ensemble of the mol2 filles located in the same directory.

```
structure36S.mol2   structure30S.mol2   structure21.mol2
structure36R.mol2   structure30R.mol2   Structure20R.mol2
structure35S.mol2   structure29R.mol2   Structure19R.mol2
structure35R.mol2   structure28R.mol2   Structure13R.mol2
structure34S.mol2   structure27R.mol2
structure34R.mol2   structure26.mol2    jacks18.mol2
structure33S.mol2   structure25.mol2    5p9.mol2
structure33R.mol2   structure24.mol2    Y6J.mol2
structure32R.mol2   structure23.mol2    06I.mol2
structure31R.mol2   structure22.mol2
```

From this data I need to make an associative array with the names of the filles (without extension (mol2)) as well as some value (7LMF) shared between all elements:

```
dataset=( [structure36S]=7LMF [structure36R]=7LMF [structure35S]=7LMF ...[06I]=7LMF [Y6J]=7LMF )
```

We may start from the following script:

```
for file in ./*.mol2; do
file_name=$(basename "$file" .mol2)
#some command to add the file into the array
done
```

How this script could be completed for the creating of the array?

Comment: `dataset[$file_name]=7LMF`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob

declare -A dataset

for file in *.mol2; do
    file_name=${file%.mol2}
    dataset[$file_name]=7LMF
done

# Show the contents of 'dataset'
declare -p dataset
```

Comment: this works well. The only problem is that the key 7LMF is always double quoted (which should not be the case!) in the assosiative array:  declare -A dataset=([5p9]="7LMF" [structure34S]="7LMF" [structure34R]="7LMF" [structure22]="7LMF" ... [structure27R]="7LMF" )

Comment: @MaîtreRenard, the `declare -p` output is showing you how the values could be quoted if initializing the associative array directly.  They are not actually in the stored values.  To see what exactly is stored for a key (e.g. `5p9`) you can run `printf '%s\n' "${dataset[5p9]}"`.  That outputs `7LMF`.  (You could also use `echo "${dataset[5p9]}"` in this particular case, but `echo` isn't reliable for printing variable values in general.)

Comment: thank you! however, the syntax with the double quotes, like [structure22]="7LMF"  is more correct for the associative array in bash, isn't it ?

Comment: @MaîtreRenard, it would be correct without the quotes in this case, but quotes are needed in general.  If the value has spaces for instance the quotes in `[structure22]="7 L M F"` are necessary.  I guess that `declare -p` is aiming for consistency by always adding quotes, even when they aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend turning on `nullglob` otherwise the pattern will evaluate as a string when there is no match.
Use parameter expansion to remove the file extension.
If the leading './' is included, it will need to be stripped with another expansion.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
declare -A dataset

for file in *.mol2; do
    dataset+=([${file%.*}]=7LMF)
done

for key in "${!dataset[@]}"; do echo "dataset[$key]: ${dataset[$key]}"; done
```

Comment: thank you! in fact I use declare -p dataset to see the dataset in the format but The only problem is that the key 7LMF is always double quoted (which should not be the case!) in the assosiative array: declare -A dataset=([5p9]="7LMF" [structure34S]="7LMF" [structure34R]="7LMF" [structure22]="7LMF" ... [structure27R]="7LMF" )